# Input element width control

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, element

the code snippet below if form an input in Joomla 3x, the "width" is somehow controlled within the input coding, but I cant figure out where.  it shows up as "element" and doesn't appear to be controllable in the CSS directly.  This is a Foreignkey input.  Does anyone know where the equation is done to calculate the width?

The auto calculated width only appear to happen in a few input types in Joomla. A little reading lead me to believe this could be in a JS script somewhere.

```
<div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 468px;" title="" id="jform_csi_division_chzn"><div class="chzn-drop"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chzn-results"></div></div>
```

Thank you

Jeff

Comment: Do you have a working example that you can show? And we would need the javascript if you think that is the problem.

Comment: What Kind of example?  not sure which code would be advantages.  I only see it in the debugging screen, Inspect (Q),  The style / width is not coded in the XML for the input, nor in CSS, this is pulled somehow from the "/Libraries/joolma/forms...i think thats right, and is somehow controlled through a calculated width based on the number of characters in a row in the drop-down-list . As for the JS, I haven't found anything on that yet...I do know there are some JS files throughout the Joomla environment, I'm just not savvy enough to have figured it out yet..

Comment: Wanted to follow up,  this is the codes from the Joomla List in the Library...

```

     $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->name . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"/>';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->name . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"/>';
   }
  }
 

 
```

I think this is the input information being inserted into the Form...and I think its somehow pulled into the information contained in the Input Line.

Comment: you could try to override what it is setting with: `style="width: 468px !important;"`

Comment: sorry slow getting back, would I put that in the CSS?  I did finally find a CSS class that worked, just really means I have to control the width per individual foreignkey input rather than globally.

Comment: you would put on the div or css, you bacily overweight the global width. You would change 468px to whatever works better.